# is this a bad approach to creating a global logger, how can I improve it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given my code, I would create a root logger instance `logger = GlobalLogger(level=10).logger` in `__init__.py` and include it in submodules where I need logging. Is there a better way to create this class instead of calling the attribute `.logger` to get the root logging class, or a better design approach overall?

```
import typing
import logging


class GlobalLogger:

    MINIMUM_GLOBAL_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    GLOBAL_HANDLER = logging.StreamHandler()
    LOG_FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] - %(message)s"
    LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

    def __init__(self, level: typing.Union[int, str] = MINIMUM_GLOBAL_LEVEL):
        self.level = level
        self.logger = self._get_logger()
        self.log_format = self._log_formatter()
        self.GLOBAL_HANDLER.setFormatter(self.log_format)

    def _get_logger(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(self.level)
        logger.addHandler(self.GLOBAL_HANDLER)
        return logger

    def _log_formatter(self):
        return logging.Formatter(fmt=self.LOG_FORMAT, datefmt=self.LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to do this, because loggers in Python are already managed by [one global manager instance](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b7a68ab824249ebf053b8149ebb83cd8578781c9/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2022) in the stdlib `logging/__init__.py` file.

Instead, just use `logger = logging.getLogger(name)` to get/create a logger at the top of each module which needs to log events. If you provide the same `name` you will get the same logger back, using `logging.getLogger(__name__)` to have one logger per module is just a popular convention.

Comment: Where would I place the customization then for the messages? In each module root?

Comment: Which customization? Do you mean the LOG_FORMAT and stuff? Just call [`logging.basicConfig(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) once you enter main (usually just after parsing command line arguments or env vars, so that the log level can be customized by user).